# Is there a way to give users the option to log in to their favorite group on login?

Tags: login, buddypress

Is there a way to give users the option to log in to their favorite group on login?  So if a user belongs to say half a dozen groups I can show those groups on the login with some sort of drop down menu and have a checkbox they can tick off to select the Buddypress group they want to log directly into.

Comment: Not really since you need the user to log in first to get the list of groups he is a member of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to what @Bainternet said.

The only way I can imagine is if you used some ajax on the username field, so that when a username was entered (on `blur` maybe), a request would be sent to get that user's groups. I would never do this, however, as it would allow anyone to look at a list of a user's groups merely by typing their name into the login field, which seems to me a pretty serious privacy concern.

You could, without too much trouble, have a user setting that would allow a user to specify the group that he/she would like to be redirected to upon *every* login. You'd use the `login_redirect` filter hook to do the magic.

Comment: Thank you Boone! could you please point me to where there might be some documentation relating to this particular login_redirect filter hook?

Comment: Here's some stuff about it: https://encrypted.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22login_redirect%22+wordpress&oq=%22login_redirect%22+wordpress&aq=f&aqi=g1g-v2g-C1&aql=&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i15l2j0i33.4413l6301l3l6562l2l2l0l0l0l0l247l323l1j0j1l2l0.frgbld.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=9bc6b30ef64520f6&biw=1271&bih=1276 Here's where the filter is defined in WP https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-login.php#L570